# Inject EntityType on UsersType.php FOS USER Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have this error on form submit:

Expected argument of type "Bl\CoreBundle\Entity\UsersChannelBrand", "instance of Bl\CoreBundle\Entity\ChannelBrand" given.

UsersType.php

```
class UsersType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, array('label' => 'Email'))       
            ->add('username', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Usuario'))   
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nombre'))
            ->add('lastname', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Apellido'))
            ->add('roles', CollectionType::class, array('label' => 'Roles'))
            ->add('channelbrand_isolation', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Aislado', 'required' => false))
            ->add('userschannelbrand', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => 'Bl\CoreBundle\Entity\ChannelBrand',
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->createQueryBuilder('cb')
                        ->where('cb.isActive =:active')->setParameter('active', true)
                        ->orderBy('cb.name', 'ASC');
                },
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'multiple' => true,
                'label' => 'Canal',
                'required' => false,
                ))
            ->add('enabled', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Activo', 'required' => false))
        ;
    }

    // 'attr' => array(
    //     'class' => 'datepicker',
    //     'data-provide' => 'datepicker',
    //     'data-date-format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd'
    // )
    
//    public function getParent()
//    {
//        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
//    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }
//
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }

//    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
//        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
//            'data_class' => 'Bl\CoreBundle\Entity\Users',
//            'validation_groups' => array('edit'),
//        ));
//    }
    
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Bl\CoreBundle\Entity\Users',
            'validation_groups' => array('edit')
        ));
    }

}
```

Users.php

```
class Users extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->addRole("ROLE_USER");
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", nullable=true)

     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="lastname", type="string",nullable=true)
     */
    protected $lastname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="channelbrand_isolation", type="boolean")
     */
    protected $channelbrandIsolation = false;

    /**
     * Ids de los channelBrands habilitados para el usuario
     * @var array 
     */

    /**
     * Devuelve todos los channelBrands habilitados para el usuario
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UsersChannelBrand", mappedBy="users", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $userschannelbrand;

    public function getChb(): array
    {
        $chb = [];
        foreach ($this->getUserschannelbrand()->getIterator() as $res) {
            $chb[] = $res->getChannelbrand()->getId();
        }
        return $chb;
    }

    public function hasChb(int $id): bool
    {
        return in_array($id, $this->chb);
    }

//
//    /**
//     * 
//     * @param int $id
//     * @return \self
//     */
//    public function addChb(int $id): self
//    {
//        if (!$this->hasChb($id)) {
//            $this->chb[] = $id;
//        }
//        return $this;
//    }

    function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    function getLastname()
    {
        return $this->lastname;
    }

    function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    function setLastname($lastname)
    {
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
    }

    /**
     * Add userschannelbrand.
     *
     * @param \Bl\CoreBundle\Entity\UsersChannelBrand $userschannelbrand
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function addUserschannelbrand(\Bl\CoreBundle\Entity\UsersChannelBrand $userschannelbrand)
    {
        $this->userschannelbrand[] = $userschannelbrand;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove userschannelbrand.
     *
     * @param \Bl\CoreBundle\Entity\UsersChannelBrand $userschannelbrand
     *
     * @return boolean TRUE if this collection contained the specified element, FALSE otherwise.
     */
    public function removeUserschannelbrand(\Bl\CoreBundle\Entity\UsersChannelBrand $userschannelbrand)
    {
        return $this->userschannelbrand->removeElement($userschannelbrand);
    }

    /**
     * Get userschannelbrand.
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     */
    public function getUserschannelbrand()
    {
        return $this->userschannelbrand;
    }


    /**
     * Set channelbrandIsolation.
     *
     * @param bool $channelbrandIsolation
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setChannelbrandIsolation($channelbrandIsolation)
    {
        $this->channelbrandIsolation = $channelbrandIsolation;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get channelbrandIsolation.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getChannelbrandIsolation()
    {
        return $this->channelbrandIsolation;
    }
}
```

I am calling UsersChannelBrand on UsersType.php because this entity have a list of active brands.. but i have this error on submit, how can i fix it?

Regards!

Comment: class' => 'Bl\CoreBundle\Entity\ChannelBrand', might be a clue.

Comment: Yes, im injecting ChannelBrand but User.php not recognize it.. i have all ChannelBrands but i can't manipulate it ahah

Comment: You are giving it a UserChannelBrand.  Not a ChannelBrand.  Hence the error message.

Comment: Yes, but i need get all channelbrand.. i dont understand how i can pass channelbrand' ids to User.php :/